# Is dynamic instantiation of a class template considered as explict or implicit?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, explicit-instantiation

If I have a class template and I use a smart pointer to a dynamically allocated instance of a specialized instance, does that cause the entire class template to be defined by the complier or will it also wait for a member function to be called from the pointer before it is instantiated?

```
template <class T>
class Test {
    public:
        void nothing();
        void operation();

        static const int value;
};

template <class T>
const int Test<T>::value = 100;

template <class T>
void Test<T>::nothing() {
   /* invalid code */
   int n = 2.5f;
}

template <class T>
void Test<T>::operation() {
    double x = 2.5 * value;
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Test<int>> ptr = new Test<int>();  // mark1
    ptr->operation(); // mark2
    return 0;
}
```

1. Does the entire class template get instantiated at mark1?
2. If not does that mean this code will compile correctly and the member function Test::nothing() not be instantiated?

Comment: Actually, `int n = 2.5f;` isn't exactly "invalid code". It's only non-sense.

Comment: AFAIK only the member functions you actually use are instantiated.

Comment: @stefan You removed the smart pointer from the code, but the reference in the text above it remained. I was slightly confused before checking the history.

Comment: If you only declare a (smart) pointer to a class template specialization, this might be a context where the *no* instantiation takes place. For declaring a pointer to some type, the type itself doesn't have to be complete. Only when you operate with that pointer (dereference, increment, add, ...) then a complete object type is required -> instantiation. The `new` expresion however does require a complete object type, hence the class template is instantiated for `new Test<int>`.

Comment: @DyP Reverted to smart ptr, but a compilable one. You could have done that yourself, you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out for the compiler I'm using (MS Visual C++), my supposition was correct that, for the code as presented in the question, the class template member instantiation would not take place at `//mark1` but rather at `//mark2` and `Test<int>.nothing()` would not be created by the compiler.

However, it seems I left out a critical part of the issue that I was experiencing. My actual class was a part of a virtual hierarchy, and according to the MSDN help library all virtual members are instantiated at object creation. So in the example above, if both member functions, i.e. `operation()` and `nothing()`, are virtual then at `//mark2` the compiler would try to generate code for both functions and the validation of `nothing()` would fail.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y5ca42y.aspx

http://wi-fizzle.com/howtos/vc-stl/templates.htm#t9

Answer (score 1):

> Does the entire class template get instantiated at mark1?

Yes. The class template is *implicitly* instantiated — only the class template, not all its members.

> If not does that mean this code will compile correctly and the member function Test::nothing() not be instantiated?

The *not* doesn't imply that, rather if `nothing()` is not used, it is not instantited.

Answer (score 0):

The full answer to this probably depends highly on what compiler you are using.

At `//mark1`, the compiler will notice that at least portions of the `Test<int>` class need to instantiated. Whether or not it does it right then, or in a later phase, is up to the compiler designer.

At `//mark2`, `Test<int>.operation()` is obviously needed, it is either marked for later instantiation or created on the spot, again depending on what the compiler designers decided.

Since `Test<int>.nothing()` is never referenced, the compiler has the freedom to instantiate it or not. Some older compilers blindly instantiated the entire class, but I suspect the majority of modern compilers will only instantiate what they can prove to be necessary (or at least that they can't prove is not necessary). Again, though, where that happens within the compiler depends on the way the compiler designers built the compiler.